# Which countries have military satellites in orbit?

Tags: artificial-satellite, military

Which countries have active military satellite(s) in orbit?

And which countries had military satellite(s) in orbit but don't have them anymore (inactive or de-orbited)?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_satellite) says: As of December 2018 there are 320 known military or dual-use satellites in the sky, half of which are owned by the US, followed by Russia, China and India

But maybe there are more countries that have or had military satellites

Comment: I edited your post to try and make it a little clearer, hopefully this still reflects what you are asking :)

Comment: I don't have time to dig through it, but the UN register of space objects is pretty comprehensive: it supposedly has 88% of objects launched.  https://www.unoosa.org/oosa/osoindex/search-ng.jspx?lf_id=

Comment: Another thing I'll add is that a number of developing countries have one or two government-controlled satellites that they use for security as well as other purposes.  Remote sensing satellites controlled by Indonesia, for example.